# Define natural numbers in functional languages like Ada subtypes

Tags: functional-programming, subtype

In Ada to define natural numbers you can write this:

```
subtype Natural  is Integer range 0 .. Integer'Last;
```

This is type-safe and it is checked at compile-time. It is simple (one-line of code) and efficient (it does not use recursion to define natural numbers as many functional languages do). Is there any functional language that can provide similar functionality?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, `(deftype natural () '(integer 0))` in Common Lisp, for example?

Comment: @Dirk I do not know Lisp. So, I cannot understand what that means. I know Haskell from the functional languages. What I want is to define Natural as a subtype of Integer not as a wrapper of Integer if is this that you have typed.

Comment: This is a type definition ("the type `natural` consists of all `integer`s equal to or greater than 0"), which is somewhat equivalent to your Ada example (except for the upper range boundary). You did ask for "any functional" language, so I gave you Lisp...

Comment: @Dirk Lisp is actually dynamically-typed so this is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Dirk this is want I wanted to ask but you came first.

Comment: Why not, @is7s? Given a modern Common Lisp like SBCL, CCL, or one of the commercial systems, the compiler often makes good use of type declarations (and type inference, BTW), generating a run-time type check only, if it cannot prove at compile-time, that the value is in the intended range (which, I would think, is true for an Ada compiler, too, when faced with the above declaration). So, I don't see the difference.

Comment: Ok, I have found that the only language that can do what I want is Modula-2 , even Ada does the check at runtime. Modula-2 is not functional language. In addition, I have found a paper about extending Clean to use subtype marks (something like type annotations), so there is no real alternative in functional programming for this functionality. I think that the ML-like type systems are not so strong as it supposed to be. Thanks for your answers. Consider the question answered.

Comment: @Dragno Modula-2 does not proof the range of a number at compile time either. You can't get what you want without dependent types/refinement types. This does simply not exist in any production-ready, general purpose language (functional or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is type-safe and it is checked at compile-time.

As you already pointed out in the comments to your question, it is not checked at compile time. Neither is equivalent functionality in Modula-2 or any other production-ready, general-purpose programming language.

The ability to check constraints like this at compile time is something that requires dependent types, refinement types or similar constructs. You can find those kinds of features in theorem provers like [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) or [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) or in experimental/academic languages like [ATS](http://www.ats-lang.org/) or [Liquid Haskell](http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/liquid/haskell/blog/).

Now of those languages I mentioned Coq and Agda define their `Nat` types recursively, so that's not what you want, and ATS is an imperative language. So that leaves Liquid Haskell (plus languages that I didn't mention, of course). Liquid Haskell is Haskell with extra type annotations, so it's definitely a functional language. In Liquid Haskell you can define a `MyNat` (a type named `Nat` is already defined in the standard library) type like this:

```
{-@ type MyNat = {n:Integer | n >= 0} @-}
```

And then use it like this:

```
{-@ fac :: MyNat -> MyNat @-}
fac :: Integer -> Integer
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)
```

If you then try to call `fac` with a negative number as the argument, you'll get a compilation error. You will also get a compilation error if you call it with user input as the argument unless you specifically check that the input was non-negative. You would also get a compilation error if you removed the `fac 0 = 1` line because now `n` on the next line could be 0, making `n-1` negative when you call `fac (n-1)`, so the compiler would reject that.

It should be noted that even with state-of-the-art type inference techniques non-trivial programs in languages like this will end up having quite complicated type signatures and you'll spend a lot of time and effort chasing type errors through an increasingly complex jungle of type signatures having only incomprehensible type errors to guide you. So there's a price for the safety that features like these offer you. It should also be pointed out that, in a Turing complete language, you will occasionally have to write runtime checks for cases that you know can't happen as the compiler can't prove everything even when you think it should.

Comment: I would say that ATS is a functional language (of ML tradition) and Haskell is a pure functional language.

Answer (score 1):

Typed Racket, a typed dialect of [Racket](http://racket-lang.org), has a rich set of numeric subtypes and it knows about a fair number of closure properties (eg, the sum of two nonnegative numbers is nonnegative, the sum of two exact integers is an exact integer, etc). Here's a simple example:

```
#lang typed/racket
(: f : (Nonnegative-Integer Nonnegative-Integer -> Positive-Integer))
(define (f x y)
  (+ x y 1))
```

Type checking is done statically, but of course the typechecker is not able to prove every true fact about numeric subtypes. For example, the following function in fact only returns values of type `Nonnegative-Integer`, but the type rules for subtraction only allow TR to conclude the result type of `Integer`.

```
> (lambda: ([x : Nonnegative-Integer] [y : Nonnegative-Integer])
    (- x (- x y)))
- : (Nonnegative-Integer Nonnegative-Integer -> Integer)
#<procedure>
```

The Typed Racket approach to numbers is described in *Typing the Numeric Tower* by St-Amour et al (appeared at PADL 2012). There's usually a link to the paper [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/papers.html), but the link seems to be broken at the moment. Google has a cached rendering of the PDF as HTML, if you search for the title.